# Unable to locate the model you have specified codeigniter-3.1.10

Tags: codeigniter-3

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>   Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: My_model
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Domain_monitoring\system\core\Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 348

Declare on my controller
`$this->load->model('my_model');`

Declare in model

```
class My_model extends CI_Model {
       function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
       }
```

File name of model *My_model.php*

Comment: Can you just try to rename your file and class to something else ? Maybe MY_model is a reserved name, I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi @Gwendal, I tried that but nothings change. Thanks.